# Get a string with ascii code objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a ascii code, for the letter 'a', and I want to get a string by its ascii code, is it possible with NSString?

Answer (score 7):

This could also work:

```
NSString *foo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", 97];
```

Didn’t test it.

Comment: In theory it's not completely reliable as it just assumes an ASCII-compatible encoding, but in practice I doubt this will be a problem.

Comment: yeah, it works reliably for ASCII <= 255, but not for special characters from foreign languages

Answer (score 4):

If you mean you have a byte that represents an ASCII-encoded character and you want to make a string out of it, NSString has an initializer just for that.

```
 char characterCodeInASCII = 97;
 NSString *stringWithAInIt = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&characterCodeInASCII length:1 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```